# How does j_security_check works in weblogic?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

I want to know that how does form based authentication works in weblogic.

My request is that once user is successfully authenticated,i want to forward request to spring controller and return the required view page.For this i have coded pages as below:

In Login Page,on clicking submit I am calling action action=j_security_check method=post.

In web.xml

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/FailLogin.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>TEST</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>TEST</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>  here
```

On successful authentication,iam not being redirected to LServlet which actually forwards request to Spring Controller.
Can any one explain how form based authentication works on Weblogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check this ? It is difficult for anyone to explain how something works while related material exists online.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html

Answer (score -1):

Hi There will be ldap configuration in the server you using it. Once it is configured then it will redirect the action to login page